# What's the meaning of ipv6 :: address?

Tags: c++, ipv6

In my code, I found that my initial client and server configurations has the `ipv6` address: `::` (equivalent to `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`?).

```
struct SslConfigurations 
{
    std::string         clientIp{"::"};
    std::string         serverIp{"::"};
    UInt16              clientPort{0U};
    UInt16              serverPort{0U};
    ssl::SocketType     type{};
    ssl::SSLReturnCodes errorCode{};
};
```

What's the meaning of this address?
Can I use this address if I don't change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a shortcut for the groups of four-zeroes (`0000`) appearing in the middle, that can be omitted. It's more visible on the example:

The address `2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334` becomes `2001:db8::8a2e:370:7334`.

The `::` means `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000`.

The `::` address has the same meaning as `0` or `0.0.0.0` in the IPv4 world: It represents all networks.

Answer (score 1):

`::` is a convenient way of writing the *unspecified IPv6 address*, which is an all-zeroes guard-value that is used to indicate the absence of a valid address.

Here's the relevant quote from [IBM's online documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=concepts-ipv6-address-types):

> The unspecified address is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0. You can abbreviate the
> address with two colons (::). The unspecified address indicates the
> absence of an address, and it can never be assigned to a host. It can
> be used by an IPv6 host that does not yet have an address assigned to
> it. For example, when the host sends a packet to discover if an
> address is used by another node, the host uses the unspecified address
> as its source address.