Address "[::]" vs localhost
a nuxt application launched via nodejs behaves differently if I access via http://[::]:3000 or via http://localhost:3000.
Can someone explain to me the difference between these two addresses?

Just 127.0.0.1 is the IP-v4 variant of the IP-v6 [::].

oh I got it, IP-v6 thanks Luuk

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879976/whats-the-meaning-of-ipv6-address for the meaning of [::]. It's the IPv6 equivalent of 0.0.0.0.

@Joe: you are right, stupid mistake of /me....
